# How can I fix classname instead of ng-class name

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

```
<div ng-class:"{{myclass}}" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{roundedtotalPerformanceCount}}" 
     aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="{'width' : ( totalPerformanceCount + '%' ) }">
     {{roundedtotalPerformanceCount}}&nbsp;%
</div>
```

My controller code will be

```
if ($scope.roundedtotalPerformanceCount <= 20)
{
   $scope.myclass='progress-bar-below20';
}
else
{
   $scope.myclass = 'progress-bar';
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here ? Please rephrase your question.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: you can use ng-class and elminate that extra scope variable like this `ng-class:"{'progress-bar-below20': roundedtotalPerformanceCount <= 20 ,'progress-bar': roundedtotalPerformanceCount > 20}"`

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] then put a bit more effort into explaing your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ng-class in this way, you can put expressions in:

```
ng-class="{'progress-bar-below20': roundedtotalPerformanceCount <= 20, 'progress-bar': roundedtotalPerformanceCount > 20}"
```

You have a typo also there. There is `:`, it should be `=`

This is wrong:

`<div ng-class:"{{myclass}}"`

It should be:

`<div ng-class="myclass"`

My suggestion for a better readability is to put functions with check expressions inside it:

```
ng-class="{'progress-bar-below20': checkRoundedtotalPerformanceCount(), 'progress-bar': !checkRoundedtotalPerformanceCount()}"
```

Or if you like to user ternary operators:

```
ng-class="checkRoundedtotalPerformanceCount() ? 'progress-bar-below20': 'progress-bar'"
```

Comment: i will try <div ng-class="myclass" > but not working it display in inspect  class="ng-binding"

Comment: can you try also the first solution (or the others) I gave you please? you don't need to bind ng-class to a variable and to set it inside your controller, ng-class already provides you a way to set classes with expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `ng-class` as:

```
ng-class="roundedtotalPerformanceCount <= 20 ? 'progress-bar-below20' : 'progress-bar'"
```